# How to try IP filter from localhost requests

Tags: javascript, express, filter, postman

I'm developing an IP filter on node.js and Express, I want to try it, but my server is running on **localhost**, as my "client" (postman), so the received IP is always **::1**.
Is there a way to mock a different IP for postman so I can try the filter's logic?

If it helps, this is my IP filter middleware:

```
ipFilter: (req, res, next) => {
console.log(`Request received from ${req.ip}`);
try{
  if (filter(req.ip, valid_ips, {strict: false}) !== null) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(status_codes.HTTP_FORBIDDEN).json(error_msg.UNAUTHORIZED_IP);
  }
} catch {
  // invalid ip
  res.status(status_codes.HTTP_FORBIDDEN).json(error_msg.UNAUTHORIZED_IP);
}
}
```

Comment: `req.ip = 'ip.that.i.want'`?

Comment: req.ip is the client's IP, on valid_ips I've an array of match logic like ::*,192.168.*.*

Comment: Depending on how realistic you want to test your middleware, I would suggest you to open your webapp to internet in order to access it from either your local network or a remote computer (with a proxy for example)